# get minimum value from sql table using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I want to get the minimum/smallest ID from SQL table where condition matches using PHP, I tried the below code but an error has occurred, ie

> Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/site/sitename/project-name.php on line 14

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thanx

```
$query = "select MIN(id) FROM project_view WHERE project_id = '$projectId' and email = '$email_in_cookie'";
$result = $con->query($query);
if( $result->num_rows > 0 )
{
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     $sectionID = $row['id'];
}
echo $sectionID;
```

Comment: Is `$con` object defined ? As I understand it, it should be an opened database connection. If no row matches in your table, the `$sectionID` variable will be undefined. You should define it before your `if`.

Comment: What's the code on line 14? try a var_dump there and post here.

Comment: You should use parameterized queries. If either of those variables contain a quote this query will fail.  Which line is 14?

Comment: This maybe          select MIN(id) as id FROM....

Comment: Yes $con is defined. I have a database table from which I want to get smallest number. The query is working OK in SQL, but when I use it through PHP to get the smallest number(id), I show that notice